# Import CSV Table Definitions into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a file of table definitions, in the following format

```
Table Name    Field Name    Field Data Type
ATableName1   AFieldName1   VARCHAR2
ATableName1   AFieldName2   NUMBER
...
ATableNameX   AFieldNameX1  TIMESTAMP(6)
```

Is there any easy way to import this into Postgres to automatically create the tables?

What if I split the file up into individual tables, and just had a csv of field names/data types for each table?

```
Field Name    Field Data Type
AFieldName1   VARCHAR2
AFieldName2   NUMBER
```

My searching has only yielded data import via copy, and table creation (based on data) using pgfutter.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the "create a table with the structure you have" part of it. I have 500 tables to create, looking for a nicer way to import them. As of this point, it looks like I'm going to have to use find/replace on my csv and turn it into creates/alters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mind I change varchar2 to varchar and number to integer.alsoyou have tsv - in order to use it, change `chr(44)` in my code to `chr(9)`. Mind I dont check for injection, otherwise here's working example:

```
t=# do
$$
declare
  _r record;
begin
  for _r in (
with t(l) as (values('ATableName1,AFieldName1i, VARCHAR
ATableName1,AFieldName2,INTEGER
ATableNameX,AFieldNameX1,TIMESTAMP(6)'::text)
)
, r as (select unnest(string_to_array(l,chr(10))) rw from t)
, p as (select split_part(rw,chr(44),1) tn, split_part(rw,chr(44),2) cn,split_part(rw,chr(44),3) tp from r)
select tn||' ('||string_agg(cn||' '||tp, ', ')||')' s from p
group by tn
  ) loop
    raise info '%','create table '||_r.s;
    execute 'create table '||_r.s;
  end loop;
end;
$$
;
INFO:  create table ATableNameX (AFieldNameX1 TIMESTAMP(6))
INFO:  create table ATableName1 (AFieldName1i  VARCHAR, AFieldName2 INTEGER)
DO
Time: 16.743 ms
t=# \dt AF

t=# \dt atablename*
          List of relations
 Schema |    Name     | Type  | Owner
--------+-------------+-------+-------
 public | atablename1 | table | vao
 public | atablenamex | table | vao
```

Comment: So I just copy and paste my entire .csv text into the `with t(l) as (values('` section? (with data type mods). Is there an easy way to inject the file instead?

Comment: if your tabs are ok, hen yes. and no - above is the "easiest"

Comment: I'm not actually using tabs, it is a .csv file, I just represented it as tabular (since I'm looking at them in a spreadsheet). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I've done some preliminary testing and this looks like it will work. I'm using this [oracle to postgresql](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-postgresql) data type mapping for that part.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is your friend, it is very expressive, you can construct your tables def using string_agg function. Have a look on the example here.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0fe14/1